# heroku,Fixieを使用したLineアプリケーションのプロキシ設定

Tags: java, heroku, spring-boot

heroku上にLineアプリケーションを構築しております。
その際に、Line APIへアクセスするためのIPを固定するためFixieをAddonとして登録しました。

ただ、Lineアプリケーションの動作にあたってFixieから提供されたIPアドレスが使用されず
Line APIにアクセスできません。

Proxyを使用するにあたって、下記のコードで何が問題なのかご教示ください。
内容としてはユーザの発言に対して、ユーザーIDの文字列を返すプログラムです。

ちなみに、Fixieから提供されたIPアドレスはポート24でLine developersのServer IP Whitelistに登録済みです。
また、一時的にServer IP WhitelistへherokuのIPアドレスを追加した場合は正常に動作するため、Proxy設定以外に問題はない認識です。

```
@SpringBootApplication
@LineMessageHandler
public class DemoApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private LineMessagingService lineMessagingService;

    @EventMapping
    public void handleTextMessageEvent(MessageEvent<TextMessageContent> event) throws Exception {

        String channelTtoken = System.getenv("LINE_BOT_CHANNEL_TOKEN");
        String fixieUrl = System.getenv("FIXIE_URL");
        String[] fixieValues = fixieUrl.split("[/(:\\/@)/]+");
        String fixieUser = fixieValues[1];
        String fixiePassword = fixieValues[2];
        String fixieHost = fixieValues[3];
        int fixiePort = Integer.parseInt(fixieValues[4]);

        OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        Authenticator proxyAuthenticator = new Authenticator() {
            @Override public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                String credential = Credentials.basic(fixieUser, fixiePassword);
                return response.request().newBuilder()
                        .header("Proxy-Authorization", credential)
                        .build();
            }
        };

        Proxy prx = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(fixieHost, fixiePort));
        clientBuilder.proxy(prx).proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator);

        ReplyMessage replyMessage = new ReplyMessage(event.getReplyToken(),
                Collections.singletonList(new TextMessage(event.getSource().getUserId())));

        retrofit2.Response<BotApiResponse> response =
                LineMessagingServiceBuilder
                        .create(channelTtoken)
                        .okHttpClientBuilder(clientBuilder)
                        .build()
                        .replyMessage(replyMessage)
                        .execute();
        System.out.println("response: " + response.code() + " " + response.message());

        final BotApiResponse apiResponse = lineMessagingService
                .replyMessage(new ReplyMessage(event.getReplyToken(),
                        Collections.singletonList(new TextMessage(event.getSource().getUserId()))))
                .execute().body();
        System.out.println("Sent messages: " + apiResponse);
    }

    @EventMapping
    public void defaultMessageEvent(Event event) {
        System.out.println("event: " + event);
    }

}
```

エラーメッセージは大量に出力されました。問題のエラーメッセージは以下だと思っています。

> 2017-07-27T15:24:31.472775+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-07-27 15:24:31.472  INFO 4 --- [nio-6512-exec-5] com.linecorp.bot.client.wire             : {"message":"Access to this API denied due to the following reason: Your ip address [54.211.114.123] is not allowed to access this API. Please add your IP to the IP whitelist in the developer center."}

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score -1):

http://www.cotegg.com/blog/?p=436

コールバックURLの登録が必要なのでわ？

Comment: Line APIのコールバックURLということであれば、IPがホワイトリスト上にある場合は正しく動作するため、問題なく設定されていると考えているのですが、ソースコード上でも設定が必要なのでしょうか？